# Repeated calls to image.png.Decode() leads to out of memory errors

Tags: image, go

I am attempting to do what I originally thought would be pretty simple. To wit:

For every file in a list of input files:

1. open the file with png.Decode()
2. scan every pixel in the file and test to see if it is "grey".
3. Return the percentage of "grey" pixels in the image.

This is the function I am calling:

```
func greyLevel(fname string) (float64, string) {
    f, err := os.Open(fname)
    if err != nil {
            return -1.0, "can't open file"
    }
    defer f.Close()

    i, err := png.Decode(f)
    if err != nil {
            return -1.0, "unable to decode"
    }

    bounds := i.Bounds()

    var lo uint32 = 122 // Low grey RGB value.
    var hi uint32 = 134 // High grey RGB value.
    var gpix float64    // Grey pixel count.
    var opix float64    // Other (non-grey) pixel count.
    var tpix float64    // Total pixels.

    for x := bounds.Min.X; x < bounds.Max.X; x++ {
            for y := bounds.Min.Y; y < bounds.Max.Y; y++ {
                    r, g, b, _ := i.At(x, y).RGBA()
                    if ((r/255)-1 > lo && (r/255)-1 < hi) &&
                            ((g/255)-1 > lo && (g/255)-1 < hi) &&
                            ((b/255)-1 > lo && (b/255)-1 < hi) {
                            gpix++
                    } else {
                            opix++
                    }
                    tpix++
            }
    }
    return (gpix / tpix) * 100, ""
} 

func main() {
    srcDir := flag.String("s", "", "Directory containing image files.")
    threshold := flag.Float64("t", 65.0, "Threshold (in percent) of grey pixels.")
    flag.Parse()

    dirlist, direrr := ioutil.ReadDir(*srcDir)
    if direrr != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Error reading %s: %s\n", *srcDir, direrr)
    }

    for f := range dirlist {
            src := path.Join(*srcDir, dirlist[f].Name())

            level, msg := greyLevel(src)

            if msg != "" {
                    log.Printf("error processing %s: %s\n", src, msg)
                    continue
            }

            if level >= *threshold {
                    log.Printf("%s is grey (%2.2f%%)\n", src, level)
            } else {
                    log.Printf("%s is not grey (%2.2f%%)\n", src, level)
            }
    }
}
```

The files are relatively small (960x720, 8-bit RGB)

I am calling ioutil.ReadDir() to generate a list of files, looping over the slice and calling greyLevel().

After about 155 files (out of a list of >4000) the script panics with:

```
runtime: memory allocated by OS not in usable range
runtime: out of memory: cannot allocate 2818048-byte block (534708224 in use)
throw: out of memory
```

I figure there is something simple I am missing. I thought that Go would de-allocate the memory allocated in greyLevels() but I guess not?

Follow up:

After inserting runtime.GC() after every call to greyLevels, the memory usage evens out. Last night I was teting to about 800 images then stopped. Today I let it run over the entire input set, approximately 6800 images.

After 1500 images, top looks like this:

```
top - 10:30:11 up 41 days, 11:47,  2 users,  load average: 1.46, 1.25, 0.88
Tasks: 135 total,   2 running, 131 sleeping,   1 stopped,   1 zombie
Cpu(s): 49.8%us,  5.1%sy,  0.2%ni, 29.6%id, 15.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   3090304k total,  2921108k used,   169196k free,     2840k buffers
Swap:  3135484k total,    31500k used,  3103984k free,   640676k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
28474 mtw       20   0 2311m 1.8g  412 R   99 60.5  16:48.52 8.out
```

And remained steady after processing another 5000 images.

Comment: Please add Go version, OS platform and CPU architecture info. Also the full code that reproduces the problem would be useful.

Comment: @jnml You can infer CPU architecture from "out of memory ... (534708224 in use)".

Comment: @Atom: Intel or ARM? ;-)

Comment: @jnml added full code. I'm running go weekly 2012-03-07, i386, Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are using a 32-bit machine. It is likely that the program runs out of memory because Go's garbage collector is conservative. A conservative garbage collector may fail to detect that some region of memory is no longer in use. There is currently no workaround for this in Go programs other than avoiding data structures that the garbage collector cannot handle (such as: `struct {...; binaryData [256]byte}`)

Try to call `runtime.GC()` in each iteration of the loop in which you are calling function `greyLevel`. Maybe it will help the program to process more images.

If calling `runtime.GC()` fails to improve the situation you may want to change your strategy so that the program processes a smaller number of PNG files per run.

Comment: runtime.GC() does the trick. The resident memory rises to 568M then holds steady. Too bad a workaround like this is required, but I'm confident the Go developers will produce a fix.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the claim about GC not being able to handle the struct above and about a need to avoid some specific data in Go is true (at least nowadays).

Comment: @mtw: GC should kick in automatically. If the program requires manually invoking runtime.GC() to ever work than I suspect a bug in runtime could be around.

Comment: @jnml The claim about GC not being able to handle the struct is true on 32-bit machines. It is also true on 64-bit machines, but with a much lower probability. There are several discussions on golang-nuts mailing list about issues related to GC on 32-bit machines.

Comment: @Atom: _"There are several discussions on golang-nuts mailing list about issues related to GC on 32-bit machines"_ Link some please, thank you.

Comment: @jnml For example: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/i1RBbt6UaSM https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/pBHdJQW_WL4

Comment: @Atom: Thank you. I have falsely memorized about a/some bitmap annotating non pointers in GC handled memory, but it was probably only discussed somewhere, not implemented (or at least not for 32 bit heaps).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like issue [3173](http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=3173) which was recently fixed. Could you please retry with latest weekly? (Assuming you now use some pre 2012-03-07 version).

Comment: OK, cool I'm running go version weekly.2012-03-22 and now the process allocates memory normally, but it seems like garbage isn't getting collected.